# How to save alpha channel render

Tags: rendering, image

The render result is below[image]

But I would like to save the image generated by switching to alpha channel below (the black and white image)

[image]

Regular "save as" would override the alpha draw, how would I save the image from alpha channel (the black and white image)?

Answer (score 1):

In the compositor add a File output node and plug the Alpha output to it and Render.

[image]

That way you can save the Alpha channel as a separate file.